# How to set Require SSL for an IIS web site using Powershell IISAdministration module on Windows 2016

Tags: powershell, iis, windows-server-2016

On Windows 2016, trying to use the new IISAdministration module for Powershell (not WebAdministration), how do you set the `Require Ssl` checkbox for a specific web site?

Reference for [system.webserver/security/access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/access) found in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` which is where that checkbox value is saved when using IIS Manager, SSL Settings for a given website:

```
<location path="MySite">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <access sslFlags="Ssl" />
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question for posterity.

IISAdministration's [New-IISSiteBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/new-iissitebinding) cmdlet really confused me.

1. To start with, this was not part of my default Windows 2016 (loaded from an aws image), so I had to update to IISAdministration 1.1 by first doing `Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force` and then `Install-Module -Name IISAdministration -Force`. You cannot use Update-Module as IISAdministration 1.0 wasn't installed with NuGet, it's part of Win 2016.
2. Second, the `SslFlag` attribute on this has NOTHING to do with the `SslFlags` for `Require Ssl`. `SslFlag` on `New-IISSiteBinding` can be set to `None, Sni, CentralCertStore`. In IIS Manager, it is equivalent to clicking on a website, then Bindings link on the right, then Add/Edit, and the checkbox "Require Server Name Indication".

IISAdministration cmdlet [Get-IISConfigSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/get-iisconfigsection) is what's needed. The following code sets `Require Ssl` on a web site (equivalent in IIS Manager to clicking on a website, then SSL Settings icon, "Require SSL" checkbox):

```
Import-Module IISAdministration
$ConfigSection = Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath "system.webServer/security/access" -Location "MyWebSite"
#to set:
Set-IISConfigAttributeValue -AttributeName sslFlags -AttributeValue Ssl -ConfigElement $ConfigSection
#to read:
Get-IISConfigAttributeValue -ConfigElement $ConfigSection -AttributeName sslFlags
```

These can be piped too. The possible values of this sslFlags are: None, Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert, SslMapCert, Ssl128 (See [Access Security access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/access#configuration))

Answer (score 3):

For those that require a client certificate the appropriate setting is "Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert"

```
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert" />
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: It's critical to note that "Required" in the GUI means **all 3** of those. If you only set it to "Ssl, SslRequiredCert", it'll work for a while and then eventually stop working (maybe 5 minutes, maybe after the next reboot).