# How can I create a list in Powershell from every webapplication in IIS with the SSL flag for this webapplication

Tags: powershell, ssl, iis

We have 50 webapplications in IIS with different SSL flags.

I want to know for each Webapplications if SSL is required and if the client certificate is Ignored, Accepted or Required.

For this purpose I want to use PowerShell so I don't have to open each web application.

Comment: I think that's all you need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-configuring-ssl-with-the-iis-powershell-snap-in

Comment: Unfortunately the commands on that site are only at Website level and not on Webapplication level. Also the commands give no information whether SSL is required and if the client certificates are required or not.

Comment: I did find this site:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47909303/how-to-set-require-ssl-for-an-iis-web-site-using-powershell-iisadministration-mo
However I see no changes in the output after changing the SSL Settings.
I tried this command:
$ConfigSection = Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath "system.webServer/security/access" -Location "Default Web Site/App1"
#to set:
##Set-IISConfigAttributeValue -AttributeName sslFlags -AttributeValue Ssl -ConfigElement $ConfigSection
#to read:
Get-IISConfigAttributeValue -ConfigElement $ConfigSection -AttributeName sslFlags

Comment: Play with `Get-WebApplication` and `Get-WebConfiguration` as those two should be able to give you those values defined per each web app with your site(s).

Comment: Is your problem solved? Any progress on this issue? Looking forward to your reply, thank you！

Answer (score 0):

To get the sslFlags properties of all sites, you may need to use the following powershell script: (You can also modify this script as needed).

```
# Get all sites
$sites = Get-WebSite
# Loop through each site
foreach ($site in $sites) {
     # Get the sslFlags of the site
     $sslFlags = (Get-WebConfiguration -Filter "system.webServer/security/access" -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\$($site.Name)").sslFlags
     # Display the site name and corresponding sslFlags
     Write-Host "Site: $($site.Name), SSL Flags: $sslFlags"
}
```

The possible values of this sslFlags are: None, Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert, SslMapCert, Ssl128 (See [Access Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/access#configuration)).

This is my test result:
[image]